# Risk for Type 2 Diabetes

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, health, health-risk

I am a 16 year old teenager.

Unfortunately I am very fat, trying to lose weight.

I weigh ~91kg my height is 5 ft 11 in, and my waist circumference is 41.5 inches (I know....)

My father has type 2 Diabetes.

Am I in the risk for the near future of getting Type 2 Diabetes?

Comment: I'm afraid your question relates almost entirely to health matters, not exercise.

Comment: By all means discuss this with a doctor.  However, diabetes is somewhat unusual in that it's easy to monitor your blood sugar.  Meters are inexpensive and do not require a prescription.  In fact, your father probably has one.  Do some testing and you can determine if you are already developing diabetes.

Comment: By the way, a BMI of 28 is overweight but still pretty far from obese.

Comment: This isn't an answer per se, but I wanted to say that you are doing a good thing for yourself by recognizing that you may be at risk and taking steps to manage your weight.

Comment: My dad does. @Cerad, after ~2 hours of eating something it shows ~140. I dont feel tired, nor have I lost weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer can only be provided to you by a health professional, but I can give you some things to consider and educate yourself on in advance. Do some research and have a serious conversation with your doctor.

You may already be experiencing [insulin resistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin_resistance). This means that your arteries are routinely being doused with fatty deposits that are binding to the walls and will stay there. As those walls get gummed up, the smooth muscles around your circulatory system constrict, increasing your blood pressure.

The fact that your father already has type 2, and that you are already overweight lends itself to the idea that you are in a home with customs and dietary habits that are at odds with health.

[I would really recommend watching some of the well made documentaries about food in the western world](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Oq24hITFTY). The sad reality is that the average American is very out of touch with what they should be eating. You most likely need to completely change how you look at food, your body, and health.

It's not optional either. You either make time and effort towards being healthy, or you will spend time and effort dealing with the illness that make up [metabolic syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_syndrome).

My advice:

1. Talk to your doctor. [There are real concerns about rapid weight loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/how-serious-are-the-dangers-to-rapid-weight-loss?rq=1), so you'll want to be monitored. Plus, you're going to love having hard data showing how much progress you've made.
2. Focus on nutrition over everything else. It is **extremely** hard to burn a few hundred calories, but it is *much* easier to not eat them in the first place.
3. Start walking every day for 30 minutes. More so than the exercise itself, get in the habit about caring enough for your health that you prioritize. Do not short change yourself. Nearly every highly successful person in the world puts physical health on the top of the priority stack because without it you can't do much else.
4. Remember that it took a while to get fat, and it will take a while to get thin. Use a good plan, stay on it, and have faith in the plan.
5. Come back here and ask us any specific questions you have, we'll be happy to help.

Comment: +1 Point 2 should be **capitalized.** It should be every fat person's **word of the day.** :)

Comment: @EricKaufman, Thanks a lot! So I have pre-diabetes I suppose. What if I just eat healthy from now on? I mean no fatty things. But I do not exercise so much? I have PE twice a week? I will plan on going to walk 30 minutes twice a week (on weekends) ?

Answer (score 1):

Good news is that you have realized early enough that you could be in danger of type 2 diabetes and you may already be in fact a bit insulin resistance. I have been able to reverse my dad's pre-diabetes purely by controlling his diet. I have also been able to improve blood lipid markers for my elder brother.

Here are my suggestions and recommendations

1. Understand the connection between food you may be eating and how it's impacting your insulin hormone and blood sugar levels. Remember, type 2 diabetes is essentially insulin resistance which means body is no longer sensitive to insulin. This is primarily a result of eating highly refine carbs and sugars. I would recommend you read Mark Sisson's article:
   http://www.marksdailyapple.com/diabetes/#axzz3S8kBTHIo
2. Once you understand the above basics, don't take anything on faith but take matters in your own hands by buying a glucometer. It's very cheap and will help you monitor your blood glucose levels.
   Read my experiment on how I measured my blood glucose for a week:
   http://www.primalbulletproof.blogspot.co.nz/2015/02/50-glucose-readings-at-some-point.html
   Also google for "Chris Kresser glucometer" and you can read a wonderful post on how you can prevent diabetes and heart disease for 16 bucks.
3. Once you know your 101, you can have a meaningful chat with your GP. You will be able to take an informed decision and not just blindly follow what the doc asks you to do.

You have inherited genetic material from your parents and this predisposes you to certain modern ailments like Type-2 Diabetes , that is you are more likely to get it, let's say compared to someone who is lean and there is no family history of diabetes. But what I want to stress on is that it's just a probability and doesn't have to be your fate. You get to have the final say because food and lifestyle can drastically reduce this possibility. Remember, food is bio-chemical information and impacts the bio-chemistry of our bodies.

Good luck.
Nitin